# Finding generators in a group of integers modulo n does not work the same way as with multiplicative groups of integers modulo n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I basically only worked with multiplicative groups of integers modulo n ($\mathbb{Z}_n^*$), so I kind of wondered why the same rules do not apply for $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Usually I would

1. Find group order for the group $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$. Be n = 5, so $\mathbb{Z}_5^* = \{1,2,3,4\}, |\mathbb{Z}_5^*| = \varphi(5) = 4$
2. Then iterate through all elements and find their order, which can only be a factor of 4 (Lagrange):

   - ord(1) = 1,
   - ord(2) = 4,
   - ord(3) = 4,
   - ord(4) = 2
3. Now all those elements whose order equals the group order are generators (2 and 3 in this case)

So far, so good. Now when using the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$:

1. Find group order for the group $\mathbb{Z_n}$. Be n = 5, so $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}, |\mathbb{Z}_5| = 5$
2. Then iterate through all elements and find their order, which can only be a factor of 5 (Lagrange):

   - ord(0) = $\infty$,
   - ord(1) = 1,
   - ord(2) = 4

And here already Lagrange's Theorem is violated, so I guess my solution approach does either not work for non-coprime groups or I am doing some miscalculation.

Comment: Firstly you must start with asking: Whether $\Bbb Z_n$ is a group under multiplication? If the answer is yes, only then can you talk about group theoretic properties like order of an element.

Comment: Please translate it to math terms for me then. I'm referring to the group of numbers modulo n which are not specifically coprime to their modulus, together with the operation multiplication.

Comment: That's not a group, and "order" does not make sense in that context.  That is, zero divisors will not have an order in the sense you want.

Comment: Before you start investigating the orders of elements, you must first verify whether $\Bbb Z_n $ forms a group under multiplication. Since it does not form a group under multiplication, it makes no sense to talk about the order of an element.

Comment: Ah okay so to be exact I'm talking about the group $G(\mathbb{Z}_n \backslash \{0\}, \cdot)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: The answer is that $\mathbb{Z_n}$ does not form a group with multiplication as 0 has no inverse element.

Comment: This isn't true. Consider $(\Bbb Z_4-\{0\},.)$. Here $2.2=4=0\not \in \Bbb Z_4-\{0\}$.

Comment: There is a problem with this answer. When in a question $\mathbb Z_n$ is mentioned as a group, it is understood that the operation is addition modulo $n.$ Your question did say, "using the group $\mathbb Z_n$". So the answer becomes that you were supposed to add and not multiply as done in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Order of $0$ is not infinity. The operation in $\mathbb Z_n$ is addition modulo $n$. $0$ is the identity element of $\mathbb Z_n$, hence its order is $1$.

As $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5 \equiv 0 \mod 5.$ Thus, order of $1$ is $5$.

Also, $2+2+2+2+2=10 \equiv 0 \mod 5.$ Thus order of $2$ is also $5$.

Similarly, order of $3$ and $4$ is also $5$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a ring which defines both multiplication and addition. And obviously I'm only referring to the multiplication in above example.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n$ is a ring, yes. But it does not form a group with respect to multiplication(0 has no inverse with respect to multiplication). In your question, you have only been talking about groups.

Comment: Ah okay so to be exact I'm talking about the group $G(\mathbb{Z}_n \backslash \{0\}, \cdot)$

Comment: @AdHominem $(\Bbb Z_n-\{0\},.)$ is still not a group. Check what happens for $n=6$. It isn't closed under the operation.

Comment: @AdhHominem You might want to revisit your question and clarify what you want to ask. Before you start finding order of elements, you should check whether the set forms a group with respect to the operation you are considering.

Comment: @Naive Why not? It's the group of all nonzero integers modulo 6, which is definitely closed.

Comment: @AdHominem No, it is not.